# Forgot the yeast in a brioche bread recipe

Tags: bread, dough, yeast

This is the brioche bun recipe I frequnetly use:

250 gr potato puree

3.5 cups flour

1 tsp sugar

0.5 tsp salt

2 tsp instant yeast

1 tbsp olive oil

50 gr butter

1/3 cup milk

1 egg

1 tsp bread improver

First mix the dry ingredients, then add melted butter, egg and potato puree. Then add olive oil and milk.

I followed the instructions but forgot to add instant yeast. And with the mistake remaining unidentified I waited for the dough to rise. But after two or so hours, all of a sudden I figured I didn't add yeat to the dough.

Is it possible to corporate it into the dough now? What can be done to save the dough?

Comment: 'Instant' yeast can be added without proofing first.  I dont know if you could get away with kneading it in and letting it sit again to rise

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will sometimes add yeast late, for instance when I'm not finding a sourdough culture to be adequate for a decent rise, or on the rare occasion when I'm getting poor performance from a particular batch of yeast.

I typically dissolve it in a small amount of water (or milk for this recipe), work the mixture into the dough, and add a bit of flour if needed to compensate for the added liquid.

It works.

Comment: I did it and it actually worked. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you made some pasta dough...
Don't know the name any longer but the potato dough was rolled out 2 or 3cm thick and rolled up with a spinach or other filling then the fat log boiled whole wrapped snug in cheesecloth. Pretty spirals upon slicing. Quick saute in butter to finish.

Otherwise it is quite the mess and fuss incorporating yeast into a dough. Your results will not have the same texture as planned but if above suggestion is not desired: a slurry of yeast -double the recipe- folded in a bit over each successive turn.